# Coefficient matrix of highest derivatives of second order linear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the differential operator $L$ defined as:

$$L(x,y,D)=c^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}u(x,y)+c \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)+e^{-c^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,y)$$

The symmetric matrix of the coefficients of the highest derivatives is

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} c^2 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & c \end{array} \right)$$

Now my question is where the $-1/2$ is coming from. It makes sense to me that $-1/2 + (-1/2)=-1$ which would be the missing coefficient of $\partial x\partial y$ but I don't see why exactly it is possible to write the matrix like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the matrix multiplication:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
         x & y
     \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c^2 & -1/2\\
-1/2 & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
         x \\ y
     \end{pmatrix}= c^2x^2 -\frac{1}{2}xy  -\frac{1}{2}xy + cy^2 = c^2x^2 -xy + cy^2 
$$
And you get the polynomial that corresponds to the second order terms of your differential equation.

In general, for every second degree homogeneous polynomial in n variables (that is, a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form)),
$$
p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}{x_i}{x_j}
$$
we can find a *symmetric* matrix $S$ such that $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \mathbf x^\mathrm{T} S \mathbf x,$

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why we can always find a symmetric matrix this way?

Comment: Khan Academy explains it pretty well here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yEiCV-xEWQ